# Tapping notification on android opens stackexchange app to main page, not the item that was in the notification

Tags: feature-request, android-app

When I get a notification on android that someone had posted an answer or comment, if I click the notification, it opens the Stack Exchange app but shows the main view with the inbox opened, not the comment or answer that was in the notification.

If there is only one notification pending, when you tap it it should show you the actual contents rather than just the inbox.

Comment: It should show the main view with the inbox open though, does it not?

Comment: @balpha It does not.

Comment: Can you recreate this now? We had some big changes to that flow on  version 1.0.23.

Comment: @kas this seems to be fixed in that it now shows the inbox opened. I would prefer it work like the website: if there's one message, it should go directly to it, multiple messages would show the inbox

Comment: @DonRhummy I changed this into a feature request for you :)

Comment: @kas thank you, that's correct!